# How to disabled or remove or hide Item selected space in react native drawer

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, and I am creating a drawer from that drawer I am navigating to different different screen. now I want to hide or disabled or remove Item selected space from that drawer. I do not want to display that selected style on this drawer.. I have uploaded the image please check it . thanks..

here is my drawer code and I want to disabled Market visit Button But I want to navigate that screen. is it possible please help

Basically I want the blue focus and entire nav item hidden from the naw bar specifically

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return (

 <NavigationContainer>
  
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Browse" openByDefault>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Browse" component={Browse} />  
        <Drawer.Screen style={{}} name="MarketVisit" component={MarketVisit}   options={{
                drawerLabel: () => null,
                title: null,
            }} 
           // enabled={false}
            />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Basically I want the blue focus and entire nav item hidden from the naw bar specifically

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can make conditional style that will work:

```
<Drawer.Screen style={enables>0?styles.enable:style.disable} name="MarketVisit" component={MarketVisit}   options={{
                drawerLabel: () => null,
                title: null,
            }} 
           // enabled={false}
            />
```

Comment: Error showing like this => cant find varibale: enables

Comment: please help..  I am new to react native

Answer (score 0):

You can still use mine as an example:  [React Navigation 5 Hide Drawer Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395508/react-navigation-5-hide-drawer-item/60610970#60610970)

To summarize and give you more context with your example:

```
        drawerContent={props => customDrawerContent(props)}
```

add to your `Drawer.Navigator` component.  Then define the `customDrawerContent` similar to:

```
const customDrawerContent = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{height: '90%'}}>
                <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>

                        {/* Tried just disabling using DrawerItemList but wasn't working so made
                        complete custom drawer component and navigate properly using props.navigation.navigate */}
                        {/* <DrawerItemList 
                            {...props}
                        /> */}

                </DrawerContentScrollView>
            </View>

        </View>
    )
}
```

The `DrawerItemList` portion will just spread out the item defined but hidden in your `Drawer.Navigator` so that it is still accessible with navigation actions.  You'll need the following import: `import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';`

You'll have to take care of some styling with your custom drawer but it will solve the issue where the blue highlight is present which is the exact issue I ran into before I did a custom drawer component.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the selected item in a state variable and then iterate throug children using `React.Children.map` to iterate through children. If the index of the child is the stored index in `selectedNavItem`, return `null`. React won't render `null` in your DOM, so it won't display anything. If you wanted to render a component that looks different you can also pass a className prop to the child that is selected quite easily.

```
const NavigationDrawer = (props) => {
  // the children of this component would be <NavigationDrawerItem /> components.
  const {
    children,
  } = props

  // the selected nav item
  const [selectedNavItem, setSelectedNavItem] = React.useState(null)

  // the index of the nav item is passed here and stored in the state variable
  const handleNavItemOnClick = (index) => {
    setSelectedNavItem(index)
  }

  }, [children])

  return <Drawer>
    {
    // iterate over the children components
    return React.Children.map(child, index) => {
      return index !== selectedNavItem
        // the first param of React.cloneElement is the component to clone, in our
        // case a child component. The second param is the props to pass that cloned
        // component.
        ? React.cloneElement(child, {
          onClick: () => handleNavItemClick(index)
        })
        : null
    })
    }
  </Drawer>
}
```